# Do transactions/call to functions of smart contracts ever happen in parallel/concurrent manner?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to set up a smart contract by which two parties need to agree upon a state. For that, for security, I require one party to say the state and the second to also say it, and see if they both agree.

I was wondering, is it possible that both parties are recognised as the first party to say the state? (this would completely break my smart contract).

Thanks

Comment: No. Txs are ordered in a block. One tx always happens before the other.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way for your contract to be run in parallel.
The second transaction will always be run after the first one finishes.

What can happen is that they are not run in the order the users called them. If user A executes the function and 1 milisecond afterwards user B executes the function, it might happen that user B goes first, depending in the order the transactions are mined, which can be manipulated to some extent by the miners.

Also, you should note for your case that the content that you send and store to the blockchain can be inspected by miners or users looking at the transactions, so unless you do some encryption of the state being sent, user B could know what state user A sent and match it.