# Reentrancy protection against multiple entries at once

Tags: security, reentrant-attacks

I'm concerned about the security of the *Reentrancy* pattern that we can use in Solidity to prevent from calling multiple times a same function at the same time.
This protection is nicely implemented here:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol.
But for my question, I did a smaller version merging the code of the modifier inside the function:

```
contract Contract1 {
    bool locked;

    function f() external {
        require(!locked, "Reentrant call");
        locked = true;
        // Do something
        locked = false;
    }
}
```

According to my understanding, in Solidity, on the Ethereum Virtual Machine, it is impossible to execute more than 1 instruction at a time, each instruction is executed sequentially, not in parallel. That's why before to execute `locked = true`, first `require(!locked, "Reentrant call")` have to be executed (and valid).

But would there be a possibility for 2 concurrent requests (let's say from user A and user B, or even from the same user) on `f()` to sequentially execute those instructions in this order:

1. `require(!locked, "Reentrant call")`
2. `require(!locked, "Reentrant call")` (which would also be valid at this stage)
3. `locked = true`
4. `locked = true`

If so, `// Do something` would be executed twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But would there be a possibility for 2 concurrent requests?

There can be many concurrent requests for miners to execute many different transactions, all calling the same function in the same contract.

So far your concern is in place.

But once a transaction is executed (i.e., added to the blockchain), it is executed atomically until completion.

So you can rest assure that your protection method works as intended.

**Side note:**

Instead of toggling `bool locked` between `false` and `true`, you can toggle `uint locked` between `1` and `2`. This will reduce your method's gas consumption significantly, because changing a state variable from zero to non-zero costs a lot more than changing it from non-zero to non-zero.

Comment: Thank you for these explanations. But then I wonder, if transactions are executed atomically, isn't my reentrancy protection useless? I mean, if `f()` is executed atomically, it should not be possible to execute it more than once at a time, right? and so I should be able to remove the reentrancy protection. Sorry, I'm trying to fully understand the behavior.

Comment: @Doug: No. Reentrancy is still possible, for example, if in the `Do something` part you call some function in some other contract. And that includes transferring ETH to that other contract, which subsequently invokes the `fallback` function or the `receive` function in that contract.

Comment: Thanks to you I'm beginning to understand. I appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: @Doug: Of course, your mechanism will prevent that other contract function (the one executed from the `Do something` part) from re-entering your contract function.

Comment: I have same doubt - if locked is true for tx1 and it has still not executed, then if tx2 will called then locked will be true and this tx2 will be discarded. then how this will work for concurrent transaction.

Comment: Seems like tx are executed sequentially - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30636/do-transactions-call-to-functions-of-smart-contracts-ever-happen-in-parallel-con

In that case things make sense.